# What is the physiological difference between people that can function on limited sleep, and other?

Tags: sleep-deprivation, cognitive-science

I know a few people that'll have 5 hours, at the most, of sleep. Perhaps 6. It's habit for them, and I don't understand how they are able to remain energized and think clearly.

Is there a physiological difference, are they just conditioned, or are they not doing as well as they seem to be?

Comment: If [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkzwi3kpd2c) and [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqGSIikqDNM) would do significantly less well, then they could not have ended up in their respective positions right now.

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/genetic-mutation-sleep-less/ but in elephants there is a huge difference between wild and Zoo elephants http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-39126993